# win8 HttpClient auto redirect

Tags: windows, microsoft-metro

When I use HttpClient.GetAsync(url),but the url is not a reachable address,but it always redirect to another address,and it return a statuecode with ok.

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;
        //using ()
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
            response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Debug.WriteLine(response.StatusCode.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                // problems handling here
                Debug.WriteLine(
                    "Error occurred, the status code is: {0}",
                    response.StatusCode
                );
            }
        }
```

Comment: do you have a specific example?  if he address isn't reachable what it is redirecting to?  Or are you saying you want to trap a redirect?

Comment: This one "http://www.fuboqing111222333888.com/" you will get a "This page can't be displayed" message,which is a the remote server cant be reched,but when you want to attach this one"http://www.fuboqing.com/", you will find it auto directs to a address seems like a ISP set to get the error DNS info?? But I dont want to get this page ,because when you use the HttpClient will always return a ok status

Comment: I noticed you're passing a handler into the HttpClient constructor - what are you configuring on that handler?  Did you set AllowAutoRedirect to false?